# Get the count of multiple properties in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to combine 2 cyphers into one for performance but have not succeeded.

I need to get the count of multiple properties unique to eachother in the same cypher.

EX 1:

```
Match (n)
RETURN n.foo, count(*) AS count
```

EX 2:

```
Match (n)
RETURN n.bar, count(*) AS count
```

I was hoping I could just run both:

```
Match (n)
RETURN n.foo, count(*) AS fooCount, n.bar, count(*) AS barCount
```

But this returns the same count for both as it is finding where they both match. Not what I want.

So was looking for a way to group them to be unique like:

```
Match (n)
RETURN {n.foo, count(*) AS fooCount}, {n.bar, count(*) AS barCount}
```

Obviously this is not valid syntax but shows what I am trying to do.

Any assistance on this is of course appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to do this back to back, all at once isn't a good idea for this kind of query, as aggregation won't work in your favor.

You could try this:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n.bar as bar, count(*) AS count
WITH collect({bar:bar, count:count}) as barCounts
MATCH (n) 
WITH barCounts, n.foo as foo, count(*) AS count
WITH barCounts, collect({foo:foo, count:count}) as fooCounts
RETURN barCounts, fooCounts
```

Comment: This took a very long time to complete but it seems to have worked thanks!

Comment: I just wish there was a more "straight forward way" as this is going to get pretty complex with more options... I need to do it with 12 matches not just 2. Worried about the performance.

Comment: After doing this 4 properties and a data set of about 60k nodes load times have gone to over a minute and adding the 5th property i got hit with: "Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database."

Comment: Are you sure this use case is really what you need? I don't think I've seen one like this before, having to find all possible values (and count) on multiple properties. You aren't even using labels here so all nodes have to be revisited each time, and the amount of data to hold keeps growing with each property. Do you need them returned as a single query, or would multiple queries do?

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon. I actually am using labels in my real use case. I originally had this split out into multiple cyphers and thought it would be faster to combine them... I was wrong. All of this data is needed for a single endpoint. I think my next step is to actually create the relationships in neo4j during import and let the cypher be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to aggregate separate query results, you can also use [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/union/) as a quick and easy way to return both at the same time.

```
Match (n)
RETURN "foo" as type, n.foo as value, count(*) AS count
UNION ALL
Match (n)
RETURN "bar" as type, n.bar as value, count(*) AS count
```

Just a few notes, both returns for a UNION must have the same column names.

Also, the "type" column in the example isn't necessary, but it shows how you can add filler if both queries don't have the same number of return columns. (Or if you want to tell which query the result is from.) If there is a "foo" and a "bar" with the same value+count, UNION ALL will keep both, and UNION will drop the duplicate (if you remove the type column).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's outdated, but just in case someone needs it, I've found another approach using an APOC function which avoids running multiple times the same `MATCH (n)`. In your case, it could be something like:

```cypher
MATCH (n)
WITH collect(n.bar) as bars, collect(n.foo) as foos
WITH apoc.coll.frequenciesAsMap(bars) as barCounts, apoc.coll.frequenciesAsMap(foos) as fooCounts
RETURN barCounts, fooCounts
```

Single MATCH, multiple Counts.

Wish it could help someone!